# pyinstaller doesn't load app icon

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe, pyinstaller

In my Application i used pyside-rcc to generate qrc file

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/" >
    <file>images/icon.jpg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

using this command

```
pyside-rcc images.qrc -o images.py
```

then i imported it to my application

```
import images
```

and set the app icon

```
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/icon.jpg'))
```

when i run my application with python

```
python app.py
```

i can see the icon, nothing wrong with it

but when i compile it with pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller -i icon.co -w app.py
```

icon.co is only another file located in the main directory to set the exe icon.

the exe has an icon but when i open my application in the title or the head the icon `images/icon.jpg` isn't loaded, also i don't see it in the toolbar.

[image]

I also tried to add `Tree('path\to\images')` but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very trivial .... just used `.png` instead of `.ico` or `.jpg` to make it work.

this didn't also work for `.ico`

```
QPlugin = QPluginLoader("qico4.dll")
```

which was mentioned here
[How to include icons in application when using Pyinstaller 2.0 ,PySide 1.1.2 Bindings and Qt 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867178/how-to-include-icons-in-application-when-using-pyinstaller-2-0-pyside-1-1-2-bin)