# Resource / data paths with py2app

Tags: python, macos, path, pyside, py2app

I'm trying to package this [example PySide systray Application](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/57caad5e7cc138b4772fd23fa7e760306e612399/examples/desktop/systray/systray.py) with py2app.

The app accesses a number of images to display as the systray icon's graphic, in a directory called `images`. The images are loaded with simple paths as shown below:

```
self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/bad.svg'), "Bad")
self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/heart.svg'), "Heart")
self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/trash.svg'), "Trash")
```

This of course works in development, but will not work when bundled as an application.

How can I make sure resources are loaded from the correct paths when using py2app?

Comment: I found that when running the Python application `xyz` from the `xyz.app`, the current directory is `/path/to/xyz.app/Contents/Resources`. I'll try stick some resources into there...

Comment: So I found that the resources were already being copied into the distribution directory. Using absolute paths to address the individual SVG's don't really seem to work.

Comment: This is probably because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534293/pyinstaller-wont-load-the-pyqts-images-to-the-gui

So not really to do with py2app or PyInstaller!