# Python PyInstaller and include window icon

Tags: python, pyqt, icons, pyinstaller

I have set the icon for my PyQt application using `self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))` and it works fine when I run my code in PyCharm.

Next I converted my application to one file with PyInstaller:

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed opc.py --name myapps`

However, when running the executable the icon is not shown. What am I doing wrong ?

---

On left site code from PyCharm, on right site from one file (`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed opc.py --name myapps`).
Why is not the same ?
I want `.png` icon because is transparent.

[image: Icon comparison]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon displayed when running an executable on Windows comes from the executable file itself. To bundle an icon with your application you need to specify the icon when building with `pyinstaller.exe` by passing the `--icon` parameter. For example:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --name myapps --icon=icon.ico opc.py
```

Note that unlike for `setWindowIcon()` the icon file must be in `.ico` format, so you will need to convert it from the `.png` first.

If you want to use the PyQt call to set the icon you will need to bundle the icon file into the executable, which can be done using a PyInstaller [spec file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#spec-file-operation). A walkthrough of the process of creating and modifying the spec file is in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11547144/754456).

Comment: It's not that what I wanted. I updated my question and added photo.

Comment: @Luk see the edit above. You will need to bundle the `.png` file into the executable to achieve what you want. The linked answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem in the following way

I invoke the resource within the code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        icon_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'icon.ico')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
```

**sys._MEIPASS** allows you to access temporary files generated during the program's execution

I add the resource in the executable:

```
$python -m PyInstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=icon.ico --add-data "icon.ico;." main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

To have compatibility in both `.py` and `.exe` you can do this:

```py
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    applicationPath = sys._MEIPASS
elif __file__:
    applicationPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(applicationPath, "Icon.ico")))
```

And for your pyinstaller call:

```
pyinstaller --icon=Icon.ico --add-data="Icon.ico;." "main.py"
```